# Feature Extraction for DDoS Detection

Tags: ddos, feature-extraction

I tried to extract some features defined below as an input vector for a DDoS detection algorithm using NSL-KDD dataset.

Features #2 and #4 are explicit KDD features.
But one like the first feature seems to need packets' information.

Can I extract packet information from NSL-KDD dataset and if yes, How?

FEATURES:

1. Number of UDP echo packets to a specified port.
2. Number of connections to the same host during specified time window.
3. Number of ICMP echo reply packets from the same source
4. Number of connections having SYN errors using the same service
   during specified time window
5. Variance of time difference between two consecutive packets
6. Ratio of incoming SMTP packets and outgoing SMTP packets

Comment: maybe the best idea would be to ask the authors of the paper for that.

Comment: I did but there is no answer.